# Only one parameter of controller's POST method is not being populated, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, model-view-controller

I'm trying to set all three objects of my model via BeginForm/TextboxFor and HTTP post. The first two parameters of the form work, but, for some reason, the last parameter does not work, and is not filled with any values that I input into the textbox.

The ActionResult in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateClient(HttpPostedFileBase UploadedVideo, Workout workout, WorkoutInputs workoutInputs)
{
   if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
   {
       if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
       {
          WorkoutViewModel workoutViewModel = new WorkoutViewModel();
          workoutViewModel.Clients = GetClients();
          int client_id = workout.ClientId ?? default(int);
          workoutViewModel.Client = GetClient(client_id);

          if (UploadedVideo.ContentLength > 0)
          {
             string VideoFilename = Path.GetFileName(UploadedVideo.FileName);
             FilePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedClientVideos"), VideoFilename);
             UploadedVideo.SaveAs(FilePath);
             ViewBag.Message = "Video and data saved successfully.";
             try
             {
                using (OPPDBContext context = new OPPDBContext())
                {
                   List<WorkoutInputs> lst = context.WorkoutInputs.ToList();

                   workoutInputs.link = "/UploadedClientVideos/" + VideoFilename;
                   workoutInputs.Id = lst[lst.Count - 1].Id + 1;
                   workoutInputs.WorkoutId = workout.workout_id;
                   context.WorkoutInputs.Add(workoutInputs);
                   context.SaveChanges();
                }
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                throw ex;
             }
          }
          // return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id  = workout.ClientId});


          workoutViewModel.Clients = GetClients();
          workoutViewModel.Weeks = GetWeeks(client_id);
          workoutViewModel.Workouts = GetWorkouts(client_id);
          workoutViewModel.workout = workout;
          workoutViewModel.WorkoutInput = workoutInputs;

          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Workouts", new { id = client_id });
       }
       else
          return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Error");
       }
       return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Error");
    }
```

The parameters UploadedVideo and workout are filled, yet workoutInput is not.

The View's code:

```
<td>
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateClient", "Workouts", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   <label>Weight Lifted: </label>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WorkoutInput.Weight, new { @Value = workoutInput.Weight, @class = "form-control" })


   <label>Notes: </label>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WorkoutInput.Notes, new { @Value = workoutInput.Notes, @class = "form-control" })
   @Html.TextBox("UploadedVideo", "", new { type = "file" })


   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.workout.workout_id, new { @Value = workoutId, @class = "hidden" })
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.workout.ClientId, new { @Value = clientId, @class = "hidden" })

   <input type="submit" value="Update" />
}
```

The View's model:

```
public class WorkoutViewModel
{
    public List<Workout> Workouts { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public Workout workout { get; set; }
    public List<Week> Weeks { get; set; }
    public List<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public Program Program { get; set; }
    public Chat Chat { get; set; }
    public Message Message { get; set; }
    public List<WorkoutInputs> WorkoutInputs { get; set; }
    public WorkoutInputs WorkoutInput { get; set; }
}
```

PS: I've tried hidden fields already.

Comment: Why the property UploadedVideo it is not in your ViewModel? Why are you using  
@Html.TextBox("UploadedVideo", "", new { type = "file" }) instead @Html.TextBoxFor which one does property binding?

Comment: It works, I don't know... is it really a need to change that?

Comment: Have you tried using WorkoutViewModel as the parameter?

Comment: @ColbyBoren that worked! Why did my issue arise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using WorkoutViewModel as the third parameter, the values of WorkoutInput of WorkoutViewModel's class were filled successfully.

Answer (score -2):

I would try accepting only one additional parameter besides the uploaded file.
You could create another model that contains the two current models as properties for instance.

Edit: To elaborate on this: Without having verified it, my understanding of ASP.NET is that controllers typically bind input from one source to one input parameter.
It might be possible to access the individual fields by accessing the Request property if the controller.